# How do I increase the value of 'InProcessMessageCount' for jms queue in jboss?

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean, jboss-4.2.x, jbossmq

I am using JMS based on Jboss 4.2.3 and jdk1.5.0_14. however the MDB pool is configured to maximum size 20, the maximum value of `InProcessMessageCount` is 15 only.

I did many reties to utilize the messages consumption from the queue.
I modified the value of maxSize to 20 in the domain 'Message Driven Bean' in the file `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml`. Also I have modified the value of `<MaximumSize>` to 80 in the section of `<message-driven-bean>` in the file `standardjboss.xml` but the result is 15 to 16 concurrent processing on the queue. it seems as it was a hard coded value in jboss

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing pool restriction `maxSize=15` for `<domain name="Message Driven Bean">` in `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml`.

**Update**

A thread explaining connection of max pool size and maxSession params: https://community.jboss.org/message/549083#549083

So max pool size can be increased externally in `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml` for all MDBs. Then maxSession can be increased for selected MDBs to actually increase throughput.

There is also a way externalize maxSession from hardcored annotations:
https://community.jboss.org/message/639955#639955

Comment: I tried to change the value of `maxSize` to more than 15 but there is no change finally I used the annotations :
`@PoolClass(value = org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class, maxSize = 40, timeout = 10000)` and `@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "40") }, ...)` 
it works fine The only concern that my code is JBoss native `'org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class'` which is not the best practice